# What is the alternate of onRender method in ExtJs 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am using ExtJS 6 and For comboBox I want display my own customize value in Combofield after selection. Like I want `delimiter`and some color change of the value to be show in combo field after selecting value. I had option `onRender(ct,pos)` in earlier version of ext but not in latest version of ExtJs. Can anybody please help me what is alternate `onRender()` in ExtJs 6 version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerTpl` config. Here is example. you can refer fiddle here. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hb2)

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var data = [{
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 20
}, {
    name: 'Peter',
    age: 30
}];

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'age'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});   
store.loadRawData(data, false);    
store.each(function(record) {
    console.log('name in store: %s', record.get('name'));
});

var combobox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    queryMode: 'local',
    typeAhead: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: store,
    listConfig: {        
        getInnerTpl: function() {     // <-- Here you can customize your values               
            var someString = '<div style="color:red;font-weight:bold;padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px;">' + '{name}</div>';
            return someString;
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for answer.I want customize value after selection, not in combo drop down list. I can accept answer if I am able to customize my value after selection.

Comment: listConfig will apply only for the list not in field which come after selection.

Comment: Not exactly this but in similar manner. I don't want box, I just want underline and delimiter with `;` eg : "ABC;" and underline below "ABC". If u can make it then please update your answer. I will accept it.